# Moving File to Desktop with Bash Script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script that writes content to a file and then moves the file to my desktop. The first chunk of code, before the line break, works well and outputs the necessary content to a file called main_output.txt.

Moving this file is where I run into trouble. I know relative paths are best, but I'm using OSX El Capitan and relative paths in bash are not working as expected. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
#/bin/bash
OUTPUT="$(ls -1t ~/Desktop/directory/inputs|head -n 1)"
echo $OUTPUT > ~/Desktop/directory/outputs/main_output.txt

FINALFILE = ~/Desktop/directory/outputs/main_output.txt
DESTINATION = ~/Desktop/
mv $FINALFILE $DESTINATION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be no space between around the `=` sign.

Your `OUTPUT` is done right, which is why it works. Change your second part to this:

```
FINALFILE=~/Desktop/directory/outputs/main_output.txt
DESTINATION=~/Desktop/
```

maybe you'll have to put double quotes around your string.

Comment: It wouldn't work with quotes because `~` wouldn't get expanded to home dir path. In that case `$HOME` should be used instead.

Comment: ok, but is my answer working without the double quotes? aka how I put it?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not saying it isn't working, and I've already upvoted it before commenting. I have no intention to change wording in your answer, but I think comment explaining potential problem may be useful. Sorry.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan - I have a related question that I've created here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702536/bash-script-that-creates-a-file-with-a-variable-in-the-filename - Just wanted to include it.

Comment: @keltar that's a totally valid point you brought. Do you want to edit my answer and I'll approve it.