# Bash Script that Creates a File with a Variable in the Filename

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a variable into a file and also use the variable as the name of the file itself. Any ideas?

**EXAMPLE 1: Filename and content within that file should be "helloworld"**

```
#/bin/bash
OUTPUT="helloworld"
echo $OUTPUT > ~/Desktop/directory/outputs/$OUTPUT.txt
```

**EXAMPLE 2: Filename and content within file should be "hellokitty"**

```
#/bin/bash
OUTPUT="hellokitty"
echo $OUTPUT > ~/Desktop/directory/outputs/$OUTPUT.txt
```

Comment: Why would you need such a long file name i.e. content (which would be huge) and filename?

Comment: the content is actually very short - only about 5 characters.

Comment: Why dont you put double quotes around `$FINALFILE` and where you define it.

Comment: @SMA FINALFILE variable isn't the issue. It's creating the file in the first block of code. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Then what is the issue?

Comment: The code above doesn't work. The file never gets created.

Comment: The shebang should be `#!` not just `#` but that alone does not explain your problem; indeed, without additional information, it seems to be unreproducible. (Though you really should fix your quoting.)

Comment: Meaning you might not have directory outputs or any of its parent.. create directory before you call script.

Comment: Can you show us a printscreen of what you're trying to do with the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUTPUT=hellokitty

echo "$OUTPUT" > ~/Desktop/directory/outputs/"${OUTPUT}".txt
```

You need to tell `bash` where your variable starts and where it ends. You can do this by using `"${OUTPUT}"` instead of just `"$OUTPUT"`.

Comment: this isn't used when you `export` a variable?

Comment: I don't understand the question and I don't see how exporting the variable is of any importance here.

Comment: I'm asking, what I read is that you use ${variable_name} when the variable is exported. Maybe I'm wrong, I just want to know.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with exporting the variable. You just tell `bash` what the variable is. Try: `foo=bar echo "foo$foofoo"` vs. `foo=bar echo "foo${foo}foo"`. `bash` cannot know what variable you want to use, if you're not telling it.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for the insight

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. A variable name can never contain a `.`, and the braces aren't required here.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it that way, just use a 2-step, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

output="helloword"
filename="$HOME/Desktop/directory/outputs/${output}".txt

echo "$output" > "$filename"
```